# Missing roots/contours in ContourPlot

Tags: complex, plotting

I have read some similar equations in other places, but it seems like theirs suggestions does not work in my case.

I would like to plot a complex equation in complex plane by the ContourPlot, the equation is ${\rm Re}[f(z)]=0$, where $f(z)=\sqrt{-1-z^2}-\arctan\left(\sqrt{-1-z^2}\right)$. The @Mathematica gives the following picture:
[image]
It is obvious that there is a missing contour, connecting $\pm i$. Currently I have a dirty solution to this problem, i.e., replacing the original function by $i g(z)=i\sqrt{1+z^2}-i\text{ArcTanh}\left(\sqrt{1+z^2}\right)$. Instead, now I am going to plot ${\rm Im}[g(z)]=0$. It works, there is no missing any longer, see the following picture
[image]
But in general it can not always modify the functions, such that ${\rm Re}[f(z)]=0$ becomes ${\rm Im}[g(z)]=0$.

My questions are:

1. What's wrong with ContourPlot in this case?
2. How can I solve this problem by a universal method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be that the missing line segment lies on a branch cut.  This issue can be circumvented by moving the contour slightly off the branch cut and excluding none of the plot.

```
f[z] := Sqrt[-1 - z^2] - ArcTan[Sqrt[-1 - z^2]]
ComplexContourPlot[Re[f[z]] == -10^-4, {z, -3 - 3/2 I, 3 + 3/2 I}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

**Response to comment**

The more complicated function given in a comment below yields the following plot.

```
f7[z] := Sqrt[-1 - z^7] - ArcTan[Sqrt[-1 - z^7]]
ComplexContourPlot[Re[f7[z]] == -10^-2, {z, -3 - 3/2 I, 3 + 3/2 I}, 
    Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 1000]
```

[image]

That some tuning of `PlotPoints` and of the right side of Re[f7[z]] == -10^-2 is necessary should not be surprising.  `ContourPlot` apparently was not designed to display contours overlapping branch cuts, which ordinarily are excluded.  Locations of the branch cuts can be displayed by

```
ComplexContourPlot[Re[f7[z]], {z, -3 - 3/2 I, 3 + 3/2 I}, 
    Contours -> 0, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

A more colorful version is provided by

```
ComplexPlot3D[f7[z], {z, -3 - 3/2 I, 3 + 3/2 I}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
    ViewPoint -> Above]
```

[image]

Viewing this 3D plot from different `ViewPoint`s shows that `Re[f7[z]]` is zero on the seven short branch cuts, but not on the other seven.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 1, please do not replace ${\rm Im}[g(z)]$ by ${\rm Re}[g(z)]$, it is not right; 2, to check if you method is universal, you could change the power in the square root, say f[z] := Sqrt[-1 - z^7] - ArcTan[Sqrt[-1 - z^7]], I do know the correct result, but you code does not show it.

Comment: @user142288  I have plotted the more complex function, as requested.  I do not understand your comment on `g[z]`, which I have not used in my answer.